# How can I continue a JavaScript if.. else if statement until I receive valid input?

Tags: javascript, control-structure

How can I continue prompting a user for a valid response using if... else if statements?  My script currently works once, but then breaks:

```
var enterNum = prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 100", "");


if (isNaN(enterNum)){
    enterNum = prompt("You did not enter a valid number. Please try again", "")
}
else if (enterNum < 1 || enterNum >100){
    enterNum = prompt("Your number is not between 1 and 100. Please try again", "")
}
else{
    document.write("Your number is ", enterNum)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm fairly certain this question has been answered by many people. Please accept an answer in the interest of sticking to the theology of the site.

Answer (score 9):

```
var enterNum = prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 100", "");

while(isNaN(enterNum) || enterNum < 1 || enterNum >100) {
    enterNum = prompt("You did not enter a valid number. Please try again", "")
}
document.write("Your number is ", enterNum)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to specifically tell the client that they were out of bounds with something this simple.

Comment: While this solution is clean and efficient, my point was that I would like to be able to tailor my response to the user instead of a global error message.

Comment: Fair enough. Just clarifying there is a very simple way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't with only if/else. Use a loop. Example:

```
var enterNum = prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 100", "");
while(true)
{
  if (isNaN(enterNum)){
      enterNum = prompt("You did not enter a valid number. Please try again", "")
  }
  else if (enterNum < 1 || enterNum >100){
      enterNum = prompt("Your number is not between 1 and 100. Please try again", "")
  }
  else
    break;
}
document.write("Your number is ", enterNum)
```

Comment: Is that else on the while loop intentional?

Comment: This works perfectly if you take out the else statement for document.write.

Comment: @kingjiv, Annie: No this was not intentional. That was the result of copy&pasting to quickly. I fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var valid = false;
var msg = "Please enter a number between 1 and 100";

while(!valid){
    var enterNum = prompt(msg, "");

    if (isNaN(enterNum)){
        msg = "You did not enter a valid number. Please try again";
    }
    else if (enterNum < 1 || enterNum >100){
        msg = "Your number is not between 1 and 100. Please try again";
    }
    else{
        valid = true;
        document.write("Your number is ", enterNum)
    }
}
```

There are a bunch of other ways to do a similar thing, somewhat depending on style.  This went for readability.  Could also eliminate the `valid` variable and simply have `while(true)` then `break` once the input is correct.  The `document.write` could also be after the while.

Answer (score 0):

use a while loop instead

[http://help.dottoro.com/ljqepqhd.php#dowhile](http://help.dottoro.com/ljqepqhd.php#while)

or

http://help.dottoro.com/ljqepqhd.php#while

Comment: i thought i might get that because i linked to them! can you suggest an alternative website?

Comment: w3schools is crappy. Use the alternatives listed in w3fools.com. My favs are SitePoint and MDN (also [dottoro](http://help.dottoro.com/) sometimes)

Comment: thanks, i will in the future. w3schools stlls tops google searches though. I've read w3fools, so know not to use them, but i figured how wrong can they get a while loop! But you're (both) right to mention the problem with the site forthe benefit of others. I suppose I could claim I meant to post a link to them to provoke this exact reaction, but I didn't. Shame on me :(

Comment: And now you've helped increase their rank on google by linking to them!  :)

Comment: dammit! I've changed the link(s)

Answer (score -1):

I hate javascript so my syntax is probably off but something like:

```
var isValid = false;
var message = "Please enter a number between 1 and 100";

while(isValid == false)
{
    var enterNum = prompt(message, "");

    if (isNaN(enterNum)){
        isValid = false;
        message = "You did not enter a valid number. Please try again";
    }
    else if (enterNum < 1 || enterNum >100){
        isValid = false;
        message = "Your number is not between 1 and 100. Please try again";
    }
    else{
        isValid = true;
        document.write("Your number is ", enterNum)
    }
}
```

Using a do/while loop might be a little neater.

Comment: Yes it is off and a better one already posted. Comparison is ==, or ===, not = and is not needed with booleans

Comment: Btw. control structures have pretty much the same syntax in all "C based" languages ;)

Comment: @mplungjan- Good catch. Comparison is not needed, but is clearer for someone who's never heard of a loop. And there were no answers when I started writing.